# clojure/lein repl does not work with all database loaded

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have used `lein repl` commond to test some operation on the database of my project. But I was not able to connect to it.

Then I found that the issue is database was not getting loaded. The only solution i was able to try out was:

```
lein run
```

this resulted in following messages:

---

```
2018-04-24 12:23:07,397 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - #'guestbook.db.core/*db* started 
2018-04-24 12:23:07,398 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - #'guestbook.handler/init-app started 
2018-04-24 12:23:07,398 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - #'guestbook.handler/app started 
2018-04-24 12:23:07,398 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - #'guestbook.core/http-server started 
2018-04-24 12:23:07,398 [main] INFO  guestbook.core - #'guestbook.core/repl-server started
```

---

then I ran the following command :

---

```
lein repl  :connect 7000

this connected to database and started repl. next commands worked fine: 
user=> (use 'guestbook.db.core)
nil
user=> (get-messages)
nil
```

---

Please let me know if there is any other way too?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do or what you are asking? Can you add more details and code examples?

Comment: When you visit the web page does it work?